Using integration tests with Language Support for Java(TM) by Red Hat VS-Code extension
I'm inheriting a pretty basic java project using maven. It's just a basic class library that is intended to be used by our customers as an SDK.
They creators of this project created a simple demonstration on how to use this "sdk" called ClientRunner. It's not a unit test. I am trying to step through it to get familiar with the project and can't get it working.
I am using VS-Code with the Language Support for Java by Red Hat extension. When I click "Debug" above the integration test main function I get the following error:
Error: Could not find or load main class com.oursdk.client.stream.ClientRunner in module com.oursdk.client.stream
I'm sure the project is probably laid out wrong. But I can't figure out how to correct it.
I need to be able to debug this integration test without including it in the sdk class library.
> tree src

src
├── main
│   └── java
│       ├── com
│       │   └── oursdk
│       │       └── client
│       │           └── stream
│       │               └── <java source files>
│       └── module-info.java
└── test
    └── java
        └── com
            └── oursdk
                └── client
                    └── stream
                        └── ClientRunner.java

pom.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.oursdk.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>oursdk-client-streaming</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <name>OURSDK :: Client :: Streaming</name>

    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>ourcompany-releases</id>
            <name>releases</name>
            <url>https://ourcompany.com/repository/releases/</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>ourcompany-snapshots</id>
            <name>ourcompany Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://ourcompany.com/repository/snapshots/</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>

    <properties>
        <!-- Java Versioning -->
        <java-version>11</java-version>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java-version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java-version}</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.release>${java-version}</maven.compiler.release>

        <!-- encoding -->
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

        <!-- Build Properties -->
        <!-- Maven Plugin Versions :: Start -->
        <!-- Core Plugins -->
        <maven-clean-plugin-version>3.1.0</maven-clean-plugin-version>
        <maven-compiler-plugin-version>3.10.1</maven-compiler-plugin-version>
        <maven-install-plugin-version>3.0.0-M1</maven-install-plugin-version>
        <maven-resources-plugin-version>3.2.0</maven-resources-plugin-version>
        <maven-surefire-plugin-version>3.0.0-M5</maven-surefire-plugin-version>
        <!-- Packaging type/tools -->
        <maven-jar-plugin-version>3.2.2</maven-jar-plugin-version>
        <maven-source-plugin-version>3.2.1</maven-source-plugin-version>
        <!-- Tools -->
        <!-- Outside The Maven Land -->
        <!-- Maven Plugin Versions :: End -->

        <!-- COTS Version Properties -->
        <netty-version>4.1.90.Final</netty-version>
        <slf4j-version>2.0.5</slf4j-version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-buffer</artifactId>
            <version>${netty-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-codec</artifactId>
            <version>${netty-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-codec-stomp</artifactId>
            <version>${netty-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-codec-http</artifactId>
            <version>${netty-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-common</artifactId>
            <version>${netty-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-handler</artifactId>
            <version>${netty-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-resolver</artifactId>
            <version>${netty-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-transport</artifactId>
            <version>${netty-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.15.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.15.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jasypt</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasypt</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}-jdk11-${project.version}</finalName>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-clean-plugin-version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-compiler-plugin-version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-install-plugin-version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-resources-plugin-version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-surefire-plugin-version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-jar-plugin-version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                        </manifest>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Built-Date>${maven.build.timestamp}</Built-Date>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-source-plugin-version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>jdk-11</id>
            <properties>
                <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
                <maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>
            </properties>
            <build>
                <finalName>${project.artifactId}-jdk8-${project.version}</finalName>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>default-compile</id>
                                <configuration>
                                    <source>11</source>
                                    <target>11</target>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>module-info.java</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>


Tests usually end in *Test.java, have you tried that? Would be the first thing I'd recommend, convention over configuration.
